# Azure Web App Failed to load resource: the server responded with status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

Tags: azure, web, azure-web-app-service

It looks like this question might have been asked before but I searched MSDN forums, and Stack Overflow but was not able to resolve my issue. 
I have just signed up for Microsoft Azure and was hoping it will be easy to create a web app on Azure. I created a Web Appp resource sucessfully with the default page displaying fine.
But when I deploy my own App using visual studio 2013 (latest update), I am getting the following error on the browser

Server Error
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

Looking at the browser console I find this error message:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

Please help
Thank you

Comment: [Enable Intellitrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683671.aspx) and look at the errors. Paste relevant errors to your question here.

Comment: I have VS Professional not Ultimate, My project is MVC 4. How do I Enable  Intellitrace?

Comment: With VS Professional, you can start from [these instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/05/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx) and then look at the output console on types of exceptions thrown by your application. If you need to drill down into specific exception, enable "break on exception" from debug menu and analyze call stacks when you hit the exception.

Comment: When I try to Attach Debugger, I am getting the following Error:

**The following error occurred when tried to lunch remote debugging:
Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging 
Monitor named 'netseft.azurewebsites.net'. Unrecognized error 
occurred in the Windows Web Services framework.**

Comment: Have you tried upgrading your Azure SDK and redeploying?